# Is it ok to say “easy to make out reasons”

Tags: meaning

I have a scenario: A policeman wantonly or egregiously declines a person's request and instead comes up with reasons for declining.

I want to say it is very easy for police to come up with reasons if they really want to decline requests.

Can I say this:

> It is very easy for the police to make out reasons for any requests.

I know the phrase 'make out' doesn't sound right, but I thought it is somewhat related. Please suggest.

Comment: *It is very easy for the police to **concoct excuses***.

Comment: You may find  [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) useful.

Comment: @jwpat7 I think the OP meant *wantonly*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your intent is to show that the police are lying to you, declining a request without justification, or being specious, they are `making up` a reason for their behavior.